# Flutter:my DropdownButton value is not taken?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

my working with DropdownButton and i facing a problem my value is not taken

is show me null

my code is below

```
 SizedBox(
              height: 60.0,
              child:  new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: Firestore.instance.collection("Category").snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text("Please wait");
                    var length = snapshot.data.documents.length;
                    DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[length - 1];
                    return new DropdownButton(
                        items: snapshot.data.documents.map((
                            DocumentSnapshot document) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                              child: new Text(document.data["name"]));
                        }).toList(),
                        value: category,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          print(value);
                        },
                        hint: new Text("Category"),
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),

                    );
                  }
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: could you provide us more info?  do you get your dropdown updated?

Comment: yes i got the list ..only one think i can't get the onchange value...

Comment: and also the hint is not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read more about StatefulWidget, here you have documentation: https://flutter.io/tutorials/interactive/

To fix your issue just update your category variable and refresh the state.

**UPDATE**

looks like you forget the value for the item also.

```
    SizedBox(
                  height: 60.0,
                  child:  new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                      stream: Firestore.instance.collection("Category").snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text("Please wait");
                        var length = snapshot.data.documents.length;
                        DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[length - 1];
                        return new DropdownButton(
                            items: snapshot.data.documents.map((
                                DocumentSnapshot document) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem(
                                  value: document.data["name"],
                                  child: new Text(document.data["name"]));
                            }).toList(),
                            value: category,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              print(value);

                               setState(() {
                                  category = value;
                                });
                            },
                            hint: new Text("Category"),
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),

                        );
                      }
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: I mean rebuild the widget, use setState(() {
                                   
                                });

Comment: when i select the one of the name is show me null in console

Comment: check my updated answer :  DropdownMenuItem   ,,, you forgot the value property

Comment: don't worry,  keep Fluttering!! :)